# The product of radii of two circles through a point

Tags: geometry, circles

The problem is the number 4 on the section 1.1 of Coxeter's Revisited Geometry, it says:

> Let p and q be the radii of two circles through A, touching BC at B and C, respectively. Then $pq = R^2$.

I've already found its demonstration.
I actually need somebody to show me how  it looks in plane.

Comment: And what exactly is *R* ? Is it by any chance the circumradius of $\Delta ABC$ ?

Comment: Is your request literally that someone produce a picture of the diagram described in the problem?

Comment: yes. I request a picture, and yes R is the circumradius of ABC.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.....................

[image]